Mockito android : Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
I'm implementing tests in a recyclerview of my MainActivity, but I'm getting this error:
Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

I have already tried many possible solutions that I found in some questions related to the same problem but none of them worked for me.
That was one of them:
android studio print - possible solution
But dont working for me.
here is the error stack:
Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:85)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
at $Proxy6.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:78)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:275)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:236)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:82)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:2104)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:2019)
at com.example.githubchallenge.MainActivityTest.setup(MainActivityTest.kt:36)
... 32 trimmed
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@5367164
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:56)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:65)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:49)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:29)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getDoNotMockEnforcer(Plugins.java:110)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<clinit>(MockitoCore.java:71)
at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:1683)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "infrastructure-maker-inline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~-Kp7pNC5BqVtBGMaApvBhQ==/com.example.githubchallenge.test-G6wS8MlXe2YS4qNYaCqGlg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~utaUTScrBpBgwSSogh3xvA==/com.example.githubchallenge-vywEfsfGfuCsRiqruObp3g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~-Kp7pNC5BqVtBGMaApvBhQ==/com.example.githubchallenge.test-G6wS8MlXe2YS4qNYaCqGlg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~utaUTScrBpBgwSSogh3xvA==/com.example.githubchallenge-vywEfsfGfuCsRiqruObp3g==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:50)
... 42 more

My teste class:
package com.example.githubchallenge

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.scrollTo
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import com.example.githubchallenge.view.MainActivity
import com.example.githubchallenge.view.RepositoryAdapter
import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class MainActivityTest {

    private lateinit var mockAdapter: RepositoryAdapter

    @Before
    fun setup() {


        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        mockAdapter = Mockito.mock(RepositoryAdapter::class.java)
        `when`(mockAdapter.itemCount).thenReturn(10)
    }

    @Test
    fun recyclerView_DisplayedCorrectly() {

        var scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)

        scenario.onActivity {activity ->
            activity.runOnUiThread {
                val recyclerView = activity.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
                recyclerView.adapter = mockAdapter

            }
            onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))

            onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(scrollTo())

            for (i in 0 until 10) {
                onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(
                    RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(i)
                )
                onView(withText("Item $i")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            }

        }
    }

}

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?
I have already tried many possible solutions that I found in some questions related to the same problem but none of them worked for me.
That was one of them:
android studio print - possible solution
But dont working for me.
